# findByText over multiple components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm looking to do some testing on some components. However, it fails given that some components are nested, but I want to simply check if the text is rendered on the screen.

For example:

```
<div>Hello <br />World</div>

<div>Hello <p>World</p></div>

<p>Hello</p><p> World</p>
```

I'm not looking to see if they're rendered inside the correct components, but to see if the text "Hello World" is rendered at all.

From what I'm seeing in my testing, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inspect the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property of the HTML node, which includes all inner text as a string.

With JS:

```js
const component = render(...)

expect(component.container.innerContent).toContain(...)
```

With Jest `extend-expect`:

```js
const component = render(...)

expect(component.container).toHaveTextContent(...)
```